# Perl "glibc detected" or "Segmentation Fault"

Tags: perl, segmentation-fault, glibc

Sometimes executing [my script](http://pastebin.com/iv9dcBu1) gets me a "Segmentation Fault" and sometimes it gets me the output below. Any help would be appreciated? I'm no Perl expert, so please go easy on my coding skills. You can view [my code here](http://pastebin.com/iv9dcBu1).

```
*** glibc detected *** perl: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000002982e64 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x32eac714af]
/lib64/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4b)[0x32eac757ab]
/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so(Perl_sv_clear+0x6d5)[0x3ee4895a05]
/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so(Perl_sv_free+0x80)[0x3ee4895b50]
/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so(Perl_av_undef+0x60)[0x3ee48895e0]
/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so(Perl_sv_clear+0x48c)[0x3ee48957bc]
/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so(Perl_sv_free+0x80)[0x3ee4895b50]
/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so(Perl_leave_scope+0xc75)[0x3ee48b8ef5]
/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so(Perl_pp_leavesub+0x11d)[0x3ee488c41d]
/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so(Perl_runops_standard+0xe)[0x3ee488a37e]
/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so[0x3ee48bb02a]
/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so(Perl_runops_standard+0xe)[0x3ee488a37e]
/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so(Perl_call_sv+0x4d6)[0x3ee48375a6]
/home/yostauto/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBI/DBI.so(XS_DBI_dispatch+0x1f22)[0x7fb85387fc32]
/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so(Perl_pp_entersub+0x3f6)[0x3ee4890ad6]
/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so(Perl_runops_standard+0xe)[0x3ee488a37e]
/usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so(perl_run+0x11c)[0x3ee4837ecc]
perl(main+0x150)[0x401960]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf4)[0x32eac1d9f4]
perl[0x401759]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00403000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 110043381                          /usr/bin/perl
00602000-00604000 rw-p 00002000 08:04 110043381                          /usr/bin/perl
00604000-02fc2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
30eec00000-30eed2d000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 9224244                        /lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8e
30eed2d000-30eef2c000 ---p 0012d000 08:04 9224244                        /lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8e
30eef2c000-30eef4d000 rw-p 0012c000 08:04 9224244                        /lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8e
30eef4d000-30eef51000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
30ef000000-30ef048000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 9224343                        /lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8e
30ef048000-30ef248000 ---p 00048000 08:04 9224343                        /lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8e
30ef248000-30ef24e000 rw-p 00048000 08:04 9224343                        /lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8e
32ea800000-32ea81c000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 9224227                        /lib64/ld-2.5.so
32eaa1c000-32eaa1d000 r--p 0001c000 08:04 9224227                        /lib64/ld-2.5.so
32eaa1d000-32eaa1e000 rw-p 0001d000 08:04 9224227                        /lib64/ld-2.5.so
32eac00000-32ead4f000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 9224334                        /lib64/libc-2.5.so
32ead4f000-32eaf4f000 ---p 0014f000 08:04 9224334                        /lib64/libc-2.5.so
32eaf4f000-32eaf53000 r--p 0014f000 08:04 9224334                        /lib64/libc-2.5.so
32eaf53000-32eaf54000 rw-p 00153000 08:04 9224334                        /lib64/libc-2.5.so
32eaf54000-32eaf59000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
32eb000000-32eb082000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 9224469                        /lib64/libm-2.5.so
32eb082000-32eb281000 ---p 00082000 08:04 9224469                        /lib64/libm-2.5.so
32eb281000-32eb282000 r--p 00081000 08:04 9224469                        /lib64/libm-2.5.so
32eb282000-32eb283000 rw-p 00082000 08:04 9224469                        /lib64/libm-2.5.so
32eb400000-32eb402000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 9224462                        /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
32eb402000-32eb602000 ---p 00002000 08:04 9224462                        /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
32eb602000-32eb603000 r--p 00002000 08:04 9224462                        /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
32eb603000-32eb604000 rw-p 00003000 08:04 9224462                        /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
32eb800000-32eb816000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 9224477                        /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
32eb816000-32eba16000 ---p 00016000 08:04 9224477                        /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
32eba16000-32eba17000 r--p 00016000 08:04 9224477                        /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
32eba17000-32eba18000 rw-p 00017000 08:04 9224477                        /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
32eba18000-32eba1c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
32ebc00000-32ebc14000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 9224305                        /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
32ebc14000-32ebe13000 ---p 00014000 08:04 9224305                        /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
32ebe13000-32ebe14000 rw-p 00013000 08:04 9224305                        /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
32ec000000-32ec007000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 9224484                        /lib64/librt-2.5.so
32ec007000-32ec207000 ---p 00007000 08:04 9224484                        /lib64/librt-2.5.so
32ec207000-32ec208000 r--p 00007000 08:04 9224484                        /lib64/librt-2.5.so
32ec208000-32ec209000 rw-p 00008000 08:04 9224484                        /lib64/librt-2.5.so
32ec400000-32ec415000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 9224496                        /lib64/libselinux.so.1
32ec415000-32ec615000 ---p 00015000 08:04 9224496                        /lib64/libselinux.so.1
32ec615000-32ec617000 rw-p 00015000 08:04 9224496                        /lib64/libselinux.so.1
32ec617000-32ec618000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
32ec800000-32ec83b000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 9224492                        /lib64/libsepol.so.1
32ec83b000-32eca3b000 ---p 0003b000 08:04 9224492                        /lib64/libsepol.so.1
32eca3b000-32eca3c000 rw-p 0003b000 08:04 9224492                        /lib64/libsepol.so.1
32eca3c000-32eca46000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
32ecc00000-32ecc0d000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 9224472                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1
32ecc0d000-32ece0d000 ---p 0000d000 08:04 9224472                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1
32ece0d000-32ece0e000 rw-p 0000d000 08:04 9224472                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1
32ed000000-32ed015000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 9224474                        /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
32ed015000-32ed214000 ---p 00015000 08:04 9224474                        /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
32ed214000-32ed215000 r--p 00014000 08:04 9224474                        /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
32ed215000-32ed216000 rw-p 00015000 08:04 9224474                        /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
32ed216000-32ed218000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
32ee800000-32ee811000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 9224478                        /lib64/libresolv-2.5.so
32ee811000-32eea11000 ---p 00011000 08:04 9224478                        /lib64/libresolv-2.5.so
32eea11000-32eea12000 r--p 00011000 08:04 9224478                        /lib64/libresolv-2.5.so
32eea12000-32eea13000 rw-p 00012000 08:04 9224478                        /lib64/libresolv-2.5.so
32eea13000-32eea15000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
32eec00000-32eec09000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 9224480                        /lib64/libcrypt-2.5.so
32eec09000-32eee08000 ---p 00009000 08:04 9224480                        /lib64/libcrypt-2.5.so
32eee08000-32eee09000 r--p 00008000 08:04 9224480                        /lib64/libcrypt-2.5.so
32eee09000-32eee0a000 rw-p 00009000 08:04 9224480                        /lib64/libcrypt-2.5.so
32eee0a000-32eee38000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
32efc00000-32efc02000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 9224285                        /lib64/libkeyutils-1.2.so
32efc02000-32efe01000 ---p 00002000 08:04 9224285                        /lib64/libkeyutils-1.2.so
32efe01000-32efe02000 rw-p 00001000 08:04 9224285                        /lib64/libkeyutils-1.2.so
32f0000000-32f0002000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 9224499                        /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
32f0002000-32f0201000 ---p 00002000 08:04 9224499                        /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
32f0201000-32f0202000 rw-p 00001000 08:04 9224499                        /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
32f9400000-32f9402000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 9224482                        /lib64/libutil-2.5.so
32f9402000-32f9601000 ---p 00002000 08:04 9224482                        /lib64/libutil-2.5.so
32f9601000-32f9602000 r--p 00001000 08:04 9224482                        /lib64/libutil-2.5.so
32f9602000-32f9603000 rw-p 00002000 08:04 9224482                        /lib64/libutil-2.5.so
3ee4800000-3ee492c000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 110405822                      /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so
3ee492c000-3ee4b2b000 ---p 0012c000 08:04 110405822                      /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so
3ee4b2b000-3ee4b34000 rw-p 0012b000 08:04 110405822                      /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/CORE/libperl.so
3ee4b34000-3ee4b36000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
3fea800000-3fea891000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 157884806                      /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
3fea891000-3feaa91000 ---p 00091000 08:04 157884806                      /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
3feaa91000-3feaa95000 rw-p 00091000 08:04 157884806                      /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
3feac00000-3feac2c000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 157884807                      /usr/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
3feac2c000-3feae2c000 ---p 0002c000 08:04 157884807                      /usr/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
3feae2c000-3feae2e000 rw-p 0002c000 08:04 157884807                      /usr/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
3feb000000-3feb024000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 157884805                      /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
3feb024000-3feb223000 ---p 00024000 08:04 157884805                      /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
3feb223000-3feb225000 rw-p 00023000 08:04 157884805                      /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
3feb400000-3feb408000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 157884804                      /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
3feb408000-3feb607000 ---p 00008000 08:04 157884804                      /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
3feb607000-3feb608000 rw-p 00007000 08:04 157884804                      /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
7fb851f89000-7fb851fd7000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 110413043                  /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.so
7fb851fd7000-7fb8521d6000 ---p 0004e000 08:04 110413043                  /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.so
7fb8521d6000-7fb8521d8000 rw-p 0004d000 08:04 110413043                  /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Net/SSLeay/SSLeay.so
7fb8521d8000-7fb8521da000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 110405769                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Cwd/Cwd.so
7fb8521da000-7fb8523da000 ---p 00002000 08:04 110405769                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Cwd/Cwd.so
7fb8523da000-7fb8523db000 rw-p 00002000 08:04 110405769                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Cwd/Cwd.so
7fb8523db000-7fb8523fc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fb8523fc000-7fb852402000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 110412622                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Time/HiRes/HiRes.so
7fb852402000-7fb852601000 ---p 00006000 08:04 110412622                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Time/HiRes/HiRes.so
7fb852601000-7fb852602000 rw-p 00005000 08:04 110412622                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Time/HiRes/HiRes.so
7fb852602000-7fb852609000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 110405775                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Data/Dumper/Dumper.so
7fb852609000-7fb852809000 ---p 00007000 08:04 110405775                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Data/Dumper/Dumper.so
7fb852809000-7fb85280a000 rw-p 00007000 08:04 110405775                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Data/Dumper/Dumper.so
7fb85280a000-7fb85280c000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 70410455                   /home/yostauto/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Clone/Clone.so
7fb85280c000-7fb852a0c000 ---p 00002000 08:04 70410455                   /home/yostauto/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Clone/Clone.so
7fb852a0c000-7fb852a0d000 rw-p 00002000 08:04 70410455                   /home/yostauto/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Clone/Clone.so
7fb852a0d000-7fb852a12000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 70410438                   /home/yostauto/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Params/Util/Util.so
7fb852a12000-7fb852c11000 ---p 00005000 08:04 70410438                   /home/yostauto/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Params/Util/Util.so
7fb852c11000-7fb852c12000 rw-p 00004000 08:04 70410438                   /home/yostauto/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Params/Util/Util.so
7fb852c12000-7fb852c30000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 110791534                  /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Compress/Raw/Zlib/Zlib.so
7fb852c30000-7fb852e30000 ---p 0001e000 08:04 110791534                  /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Compress/Raw/Zlib/Zlib.so
7fb852e30000-7fb852e31000 rw-p 0001e000 08:04 110791534                  /usr/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Compress/Raw/Zlib/Zlib.so
7fb852e31000-7fb852e36000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 110414506                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/File/Glob/Glob.so
7fb852e36000-7fb853035000 ---p 00005000 08:04 110414506                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/File/Glob/Glob.so
7fb853035000-7fb853036000 rw-p 00004000 08:04 110414506                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/File/Glob/Glob.so
7fb853036000-7fb85303a000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 9224292                    /lib64/libnss_dns-2.5.so
7fb85303a000-7fb853239000 ---p 00004000 08:04 9224292                    /lib64/libnss_dns-2.5.so
7fb853239000-7fb85323a000 r--p 00003000 08:04 9224292                    /lib64/libnss_dns-2.5.so
7fb85323a000-7fb85323b000 rw-p 00004000 08:04 9224292                    /lib64/libnss_dns-2.5.so
7fb85323b000-7fb853245000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 9224294                    /lib64/libnss_files-2.5.so
7fb853245000-7fb853444000 ---p 0000a000 08:04 9224294                    /lib64/libnss_files-2.5.so
7fb853444000-7fb853445000 r--p 00009000 08:04 9224294                    /lib64/libnss_files-2.5.so
7fb853445000-7fb853446000 rw-p 0000a000 08:04 9224294                    /lib64/libnss_files-2.5.so
7fb853446000-7fb85344b000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 110412590                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Socket/Socket.so
7fb85344b000-7fb85364a000 ---p 00005000 08:04 110412590                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Socket/Socket.so
7fb85364a000-7fb85364b000 rw-p 00004000 08:04 110412590                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Socket/Socket.so
7fb85364b000-7fb853667000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 110412428                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/POSIX/POSIX.so
7fb853667000-7fb853867000 ---p 0001c000 08:04 110412428                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/POSIX/POSIX.so
7fb853867000-7fb853868000 rw-p 0001c000 08:04 110412428                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/POSIX/POSIX.so
7fb853868000-7fb853888000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 56328843                   /home/yostauto/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBI/DBI.so
7fb853888000-7fb853a87000 ---p 00020000 08:04 56328843                   /home/yostauto/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBI/DBI.so
7fb853a87000-7fb853a88000 rw-p 0001f000 08:04 56328843                   /home/yostauto/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBI/DBI.so
7fb853a88000-7fb853a94000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 56328198                   /home/yostauto/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Text/CSV_XS/CSV_XS.so
7fb853a94000-7fb853c93000 ---p 0000c000 08:04 56328198                   /home/yostauto/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Text/CSV_XS/CSV_XS.so
7fb853c93000-7fb853c94000 rw-p 0000b000 08:04 56328198                   /home/yostauto/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Text/CSV_XS/CSV_XS.so
7fb853c94000-7fb853c9f000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 110412967                  /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/HTML/Parser/Parser.so
7fb853c9f000-7fb853e9e000 ---p 0000b000 08:04 110412967                  /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/HTML/Parser/Parser.so
7fb853e9e000-7fb853e9f000 rw-p 0000a000 08:04 110412967                  /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/HTML/Parser/Parser.so
7fb853e9f000-7fb853ebb000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 110413015                  /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/List/MoreUtils/MoreUtils.so
7fb853ebb000-7fb8540bb000 ---p 0001c000 08:04 110413015                  /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/List/MoreUtils/MoreUtils.so
7fb8540bb000-7fb8540bc000 rw-p 0001c000 08:04 110413015                  /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/List/MoreUtils/MoreUtils.so
7fb8540bc000-7fb8540c8000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 110412819                  /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Params/Validate/Validate.so
7fb8540c8000-7fb8542c7000 ---p 0000c000 08:04 110412819                  /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Params/Validate/Validate.so
7fb8542c7000-7fb8542c8000 rw-p 0000b000 08:04 110412819                  /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Params/Validate/Validate.so
7fb8542c8000-7fb8542cd000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 110414454                  /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DateTime/DateTime.so
7fb8542cd000-7fb8544cc000 ---p 00005000 08:04 110414454                  /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DateTime/DateTime.so
7fb8544cc000-7fb8544cd000 rw-p 00004000 08:04 110414454                  /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/DateTime/DateTime.so
7fb8544cd000-7fb8544d9000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 110412715                  /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/List/Util/Util.so
7fb8544d9000-7fb8546d8000 ---p 0000c000 08:04 110412715                  /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/List/Util/Util.so
7fb8546d8000-7fb8546d9000 rw-p 0000b000 08:04 110412715                  /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/List/Util/Util.so
7fb8546d9000-7fb8546e2000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 110405801                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Encode/Encode.so
7fb8546e2000-7fb8548e1000 ---p 00009000 08:04 110405801                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Encode/Encode.so
7fb8548e1000-7fb8548e2000 rw-p 00008000 08:04 110405801                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Encode/Encode.so
7fb8548e2000-7fb8548e5000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 110412420                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/MIME/Base64/Base64.so
7fb8548e5000-7fb854ae4000 ---p 00003000 08:04 110412420                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/MIME/Base64/Base64.so
7fb854ae4000-7fb854ae5000 rw-p 00002000 08:04 110412420                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/MIME/Base64/Base64.so
7fb854ae5000-7fb854ae8000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 110412398                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so
7fb854ae8000-7fb854ce7000 ---p 00003000 08:04 110412398                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so
7fb854ce7000-7fb854ce8000 rw-p 00002000 08:04 110412398                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/Fcntl/Fcntl.so
7fb854ce8000-7fb854cec000 r-xp 00000000 08:04 110412414                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/IO/IO.so
7fb854cec000-7fb854eeb000 ---p 00004000 08:04 110412414                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/IO/IO.so
7fb854eeb000-7fb854eec000 rw-p 00003000 08:04 110412414                  /usr/lib64/perl5/5.8.8/x86_64-linux-thread-multi/auto/IO/IO.so
7fb854eec000-7fb854f12000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fb854f28000-7fb854f2a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7fffe55a9000-7fffe55ca000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fffe55ff000-7fffe5600000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
/bin/sh: line 1: 15018 Aborted                 perl /home/user/emailservice/send.pl
```

Comment: The bug in question is in Perl itself or in an XS module. Running with `valgrind` could be useful

Comment: does it still happen with a newer perl?  (5.8.8 is almost 9 years old)  you can easily install and try newer versions with http://perlbrew.pl